# Store a reference to the underlying buffer from a struct that doesn't live long enough

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I'm attempting to write an incremental XML parser in Rust using [quick_xml](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.20.0/quick_xml/index.html).

Some of the XML files will not fit in memory (on my laptop) so I'm trying to only store relevant chunks of each file in a buffer of `Vec<u8>`.

Within each file chunk of `Vec<u8>` I want to store borrows to slices in some struct `Data`

quick_xml provides a `read_event` method which appends to the buffer and returns a `quick_xml::events::Event` (an enum containing a struct with a `buf: Cow<'a, [u8]>` field which borrows from the buffer)

Essentially I want to take the data referenced by the `Event` and store it in my `Data` struct.

However the borrow checker has a heart attack because the `Event` only lives for the call to `read_event` and I'm trying to keep a reference to it that lives as long as the data in the buffer.

The code below is the implementation of what I have tried to describe above. Could I get some help in storing a borrow to the underlying `buf` from an `Event`?

```
use quick_xml::events::Event;
use quick_xml::Reader;

const XML: &str = r#"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RUN_SET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RUN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" alias="HAP1 gene trap unselected control dataset" accession="SRR2034585" center_name="Stanford University">
    <IDENTIFIERS>
      <PRIMARY_ID>SRR2034585</PRIMARY_ID>
      <SUBMITTER_ID namespace="Stanford University">HAP1 gene trap unselected control dataset</SUBMITTER_ID>
    </IDENTIFIERS>
    <EXPERIMENT_REF accession="SRX1034759"/>
  </RUN>
</RUN_SET>
"#;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data<'a> {
    primary_id: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    experiment_ref: Option<&'a [u8]>,
}


fn main() {
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut reader = Reader::from_str(XML);
    let mut depth = 0;
    let mut path: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    reader.expand_empty_elements(true);
    let mut data = Data { primary_id: None, experiment_ref: None };
    loop {
        match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {
            Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
                depth += 1;
                path.push(b"/"[0]);
                path.append(&mut e.name().to_vec());

                if path == "/RUN_SET/RUN/EXPERIMENT_REF".as_bytes() {
                    let experiment_ref = // What to put here?
                    data = Data { experiment_ref, ..data };
                }
            }
            Ok(Event::End(ref e)) => {
                depth -= 1;
                path.truncate(path.len() - e.name().len() - 1);
            }
            Ok(Event::Eof) => { break; }
            _ => {}
        }
        if depth == 1 {
            println!("{:?}", data);
            buf.clear();
            path.clear();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `read_event` will cause the buffer to expand if necessary, which can change its address, so any references become invalid. Specifically, you are trying to call `read_event`, store a reference (`data`) pointing into the buffer, then call `read_event` again which can move the buffer.

It seems the best way to solve this is to move/clone the event name so that its lifetime is not bound to the buffer. Frustratingly, it seems that `quick_xml::events::BytesStart<'a>` exposes no way to directly move the underlying `Cow<'a, [u8]>` so we have to store the `BytesStart` object itself in order to avoid a potentially unnecessary clone.

Here is one way to do this. I made significant changes to the code in order to more accurately/efficiently do what I think you intended:

```rust
use quick_xml::events::Event;
use quick_xml::Reader;

const XML: &str = r#"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RUN_SET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RUN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" alias="HAP1 gene trap unselected control dataset" accession="SRR2034585" center_name="Stanford University">
    <IDENTIFIERS>
      <PRIMARY_ID>SRR2034585</PRIMARY_ID>
      <SUBMITTER_ID namespace="Stanford University">HAP1 gene trap unselected control dataset</SUBMITTER_ID>
    </IDENTIFIERS>
    <EXPERIMENT_REF accession="SRX1034759"/>
  </RUN>
</RUN_SET>
"#;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data<'a> {
    primary_id: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    experiment_ref: Option<quick_xml::events::BytesStart<'static>>,
}

fn main() {
    let target: &[&[u8]] = &[b"RUN_SET", b"RUN", b"EXPERIMENT_REF"];
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut reader = Reader::from_str(XML);
    let mut depth = 0;
    let mut good = 0;
    reader.expand_empty_elements(true);
    let mut data = Data {
        primary_id: None,
        experiment_ref: None,
    };
    loop {
        match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {
            Ok(Event::Start(e)) => {
                if depth == good && target.get(depth) == Some(&e.name()) {
                    good += 1;
                    if good == target.len() {
                        data = Data {
                            experiment_ref: Some(e.into_owned()),
                            ..data
                        };
                    }
                }
                depth += 1;
            }
            Ok(Event::End(_)) => {
                depth -= 1;
                good = good.min(depth);
            }
            Ok(Event::Eof) => {
                buf.clear();
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
        buf.clear();
    }
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The into_owned() method seems to be the key part I was missing.

Comment: Just some additional detail I discovered, `quick_xml` uses [extend from slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice) internally which may cause the address to change. If there was a drop in replacement for a `&mut Vec<u8>` where you could control the behavior of this method, then happy days?

Comment: I suppose it could be updated to work with something like [`array_vec`](https://docs.rs/array-vec), is that what you're asking?

Comment: Whoops, I meant [`arrayvec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec), that other crate looks strange.

Comment: Oh cool, yeah exactly like that. I'm very new to rust, and not all familiar with the ecosystem. That looks promising.

Comment: Just note that support would need to be added to the library itself. Unless you have a particular reason that you need to use `arrayvec` (e.g. no heap), I’d stick to normal `Vec`.

Comment: I'd just like to store a reference to to the `buf` rather than a copy/move. I experimented with some unsafe code doing this, I simply created my `buf` with enough capacity that it would not need to change address. It's awful code that would make the rust gods cry, however in processing ~55gb of xml this method took my laptop ~4min rather than my first attempt which took ~20min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226116/discussion-between-coder-256-and-james-schinner).